# Do ores all spawn as a 'set'?

Tags: terraria

With v1.2 there are several alternate ores available. With every world generation only one of each below 7 pairs will be available (i.e. if the world contains Tin then it will not contain Copper etc.) :-

Tin / Copper
Iron / Lead
Tungsten / Silver
Gold / Platinum
Palladium / Cobalt
Orichalcum / Mythril
Titanium / Adamantite

So my question is, do the ores spawn as a 'set' i.e. if the world contains Tin, would it also always contain Iron, Tungsten, Gold, Palladium ... etc.? Or does every ore type have a 50/50 chance to be one or the other?

Reason I ask is because I want to collect all armor types and I want to know roughly how many worlds I need to generate to find all the ore types (esp. hardmode ores)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I couldn't find anything on the [wiki](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Ores) that states this, but on my two personal worlds, I have ores from each "set".
For example, I have:

- Tin
- Iron
- Tungsten
- Platinum
- Orichalum
- Titanium

in one world, but in the other world, I have:

- Copper
- Iron
- Silver
- Gold
- Palladium
- Orichalum
- Adamantite

So it is probable that it is a 50/50 chance that you will get one ore or its variant for each ore.

Comment: Hence, the number of worlds you would need to generate to be able to mine every single ore is somewhat unpredictable.

Comment: I can corroborate this as well. During world generation, each tier of ore has a chance of being replaced by the "alternative" ore, and each tier seems to be chosen independently.

Answer (score 1):

In this [other wiki page](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ores) the following paragraph can be found:

> Each hardmode ore is chosen at the moment you break the first three altars in the world. You can choose the ores you like by quitting your world without saving (by ending the task or killing the process) after smashing your first altars. It is easier done with a server.

Which tends to indicate that the hardmode ores are not "linked" together (and - more interestingly - that they can be chosen, which limits the number of world to generate in order to cover the whole ore spectrum); this is coherent with the examples provided by NovaSword, where one world contains Orichalcum and Titanium, and the second one contains Orichalcum and Adamantite (as tier 2 and 3 hardmode ores).

Comment: "basic ones seem to be" - are the basic ones linked though? Seems like NovaSword got Tungsten and Platinum which means they are not necessarily linked ..

Comment: True, I did not notice the Iron (a pre 1.2 ore) in the middle of the Tin, Tungsten and Platinum (all post 1.2) in its first series... I will edit my answer accordingly. I've personally never encountered such a configuration, hence my conclusion. Here come the limits of empiricism. :)

Answer (score -3):

I think there is a chanse to get both because I got tin and copper and iron and lead and silver and gold in one world

Comment: I call BS on this. Analysis of the source code indicates that only one type of ore spawns for each tier in a given world.